# Google Analytics referral incorrect

Tags: php, google-analytics, referrals

Goodmorning Lads,

Today I checked out my referals in analytics which seems to be wrong.

Ok, this is what I'm doing.
I've made some banners on zuidwolde.nl on the homepage (I count the clicks on the banner, when clicked it'll forward the page too the url of the domain from the add).

The visitors seems to be correct in analytics of domain2 but the referals from domain1 ain't right.

How do I forward the user:

Homepage Add:

```
echo '<a href="http://www.zuidwolde.nl?ond=go&id='.$row->websiteID.'&href='.urlencode($row->url).'"><img width="166" src="http://www.zuidwolde.nl/'.$row->foto.'"></a>';
```

Go.php

```
Update::hits(intval($_GET['id']));
echo '<h1>You're getting redirected, wait a second.</h1>';
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://'.$_GET['href'].'" />';
exit();
```

I suppose a meta refresh results in a new visitor on domain2, am I right?

What could the problem be....

Kind Regards,

Jordy

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible issues besides the meta refresh.

If you have GA tracking on *both the two different domains*, you must ensure that:

**(1)** the tracking code is configured properly for cross-domain tracking so that referrer information is configured properly. Each different domain should have the `_setDomainName` function configured accordingly.

Also to maintain the continuity of the visitor across the different sites, the `_setAllowLinker` function should be added to the page tracking.

```
 _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain_here']);
 _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
```

**(2)** And then for all of the banner links apply the GA `_link` function, for example:

```
<a href="www.blog-hosting-service.com/myBlog"
onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', 'www.blog-hosting-service.com/myBlog']); return false;">View My Blog</a>
```

More details can be found at:
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html

---

If you *do not have the tracking for all* of the different domains under the same GA account, and you want to track the referral data for banner links on a different domain from the target domain, you can apply **campaign tagging conventions** to the URLs of the banner links.

http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55540

For example, you can set the `source` campaign query param to the URI of the first domain that hosts the banner links.

In the GA reporting UI, the data will appear under Traffic Sources report under Campaigns.